# How to properly use injecting function in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to use a injected debounce function inside my method

plugin.js

```js
export default (context, inject) => {
  const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
      var context = this,
        args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
  };
  inject("debounce", debounce);
}
```

what I'm currently using, is there any cons of this?

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.onInput = this.$debounce(this.onInput, 500)
  },
  methods: {
    onInput() {
      this.debounceNumber = this.number
    }
  },
}
```

and what I try/want to use but not working

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onInput: this.$debounce(function() {
      this.debounceNumber = this.number
    }, 500)
  },
}
```